# how do you declare a lambda function using typedef and then use it by passing to a function?

Tags: c++, lambda, parameters

I'm learning C++ at the moment, and very confused with Lambda function's syntax

I want to define the lambda at the top of a unit, e.g.

```
   typedef const std::function<void (bool)> bitloop;
```

or

```
   typedef void bitloop(bool bit, int idx);
```

later, accept a lambda into a function in a class, e.g, in my Bits class, there is a method forEach

```
void forEach(const bitloop loop){
 for (int i = 0; i<=fCount-1;i++){
    loop(this->isSet(i),i);  
  }   
}
```

and then finally be able to write different loop functions later on, passing out a value, and the loop index, so that I can capture variables in local scope e.g.

```
bits.forEach([&](bool on, int i){ 
      output("index" + to_string(count));   //count is locally declared variable
  });
```

if I remove the &, it works fine with the 2nd type def, but then I can't capture the count var.

Can somebody explain where I'm going wrong with this, and if it's a valid approach?

Comment: *"explain where I'm going wrong"* And what's wrong? Any compiler errors? Can you make a [mcve] and post the errors verbatim?

Comment: github unit  https://github.com/DerekSeymour71/c---stuff/blob/master/countdistinctslices/.vscode/binarygap.cpp

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Lambdas can be converted to a `std::function` or passed to a template function. The latter is usually the better option if possible,

Comment: How does the duplicate answers the question?? @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: From what I can gather, you are simply missing the second parameter of your function signature: `std::function<void (bool)>` -> `std::function<void (bool, int)>`. The second approach with the function type typedef does not work, because lambdas with captures don't decay to function pointers. Note that neither of the two typedefs are lambda types. Each lambda has its own unique type.

Comment: @DerekSeymour You need to post any error message you get verbatim in the question together with a [repro] producing that error message. (click `edit` to do so)

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'BitArray::forEach(main()::<lambda(bool, int)>)'
       });

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot It covered the problem with `typedef void bitloop(bool bit, int idx);`, but apparently that isn't what OP is trying to use.  Getting the parameter list in the `std::function` typedef fixes the problem.

Comment: I'll try and get a minimal example up, but it won't be today, thanks for the info so far, I don't think I'm explaining myself properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, your second `typedef` is actually correct but the signature of your first `typedef` is incorrect. This is how I would declare the [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
// T1 : function object
typedef std::function<void(bool, int)> T1;

// T2 : pointer to function
typedef void (*T2)(bool, int);
```

As you have already observed, ***lambda functions that capture local variables***, do not currently work as *function arguments* with `T2` (*see comments on this page*). The code shown below, highlights this issue and reproduces the compiler error.

```
struct Bits
{
  void forEach(const T2 &loop)
  {
    //...
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int i = 0; // local variable
  auto function1 = [](bool, int){ /**/ };
  auto function2 = [&i](bool, int){ /**/ };
  Bits bits;
  bits.forEach(function1); // OK
  //// if you uncomment the next line, the compiler would generate the following error
  //// [Error] no matching function for call to 'Bits::forEach(main(int, char**)::<lambda(bool, int)>)'
  //bits.forEach(function2);
```

***lambda functions that capture local variables*** however, work perfectly as *function arguments* with `T1`.

```
struct Bits
{
  void forEach(const T1 &loop)
  {
    //...
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int i = 0; // local variable
  Bits bits;
  auto function1 = [](bool, int){ /**/ };
  auto function2 = [&i](bool, int){ /**/ };
  bits.forEach(function1); // OK
  bits.forEach(function2); // OK
```

Secondly, there is another way to use a lambda as *function argument* without explicitly declaring `std::function` or a function type ...That's right, it involves the use of [function templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template).

```
struct Bits
{
  template<typename T3> void forEach(const T3 &loop)
  {
    //...
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int i = 0; // local variable
  Bits bits;
  auto function1 = [](bool, int){ /**/ };
  auto function2 = [&i](bool, int){ /**/ };
  std::function<void(bool, int)> function3 =  = [&i](bool, int){ /**/ };
  bits.forEach(function1); // OK
  bits.forEach(function2); // OK
  bits.forEach(function3); // OK
  bits.forEach([&i](bool, int){ /**/ }); // OK
```

And you are also right, that is how to define a ***lambda function that captures all local variables***.

```
int i = 0; // local variable
Bits bits;
bits.forEach([&](bool, int){ /**/ }); // OK
```

For other lambda capture options, see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture).

Comment: Actually, I just tested it on my compiler and it has the same behaviour with or without `&` at global scope. But it seems to be required at function scope.

Comment: Yes that is what "*local variable*" usually refers to. Capture of global variables behaves differently.

Comment: thanks, I would just add you also need to add #include <functional>. onto the next issue now....

Comment: @DerekSeymour That is always required to use `std::function`. It is however often preferable to use the template approach, since the `std::function` approach usually has significant runtime overhead. Then `#include<functional>` is not required.

Comment: @DerekSeymour Thanks for the question, I'm glad we could help. You will find useful information about function templates on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) ..cheers!

Comment: Nice one Josh, I'm busy at the moment doing some codility questions which is also helping me learn C++.

Comment: @josh7115 The typedef for the function pointer can be done directly: `typedef void (*T2)(bool, int);`. The `using` keyword (since C++11) is also a clearer alternative to define type aliases: `using T2 = void(*)(bool, int);`. OP was also not wrong with the typedef. You can typedef the type of the function, rather than a function pointer. That is what OP was doing correctly. If a function type is used as function parameter it is interpreted as the corresponding function pointer type instead (similar to `int[]` vs `int*` in function parameters).

Comment: `typedef (*T2)(bool, int);` -> `typedef void (*T2)(bool, int);`